# Can't run Eclipse from /opt

Tags: linux, java, eclipse, arch-linux

I'm playing with Arch x64, and I downloaded the Eclipse Juno platform without any plugins etc. I extracted it into `/opt`, made a launcher on my desktop, and when it runs, it produces this error message:

[image]

[This is the log](http://pastebin.com/4hDuz6LH)

JDK 1.6 is also installed in `/opt`, and the `bin` for JDK and JRE are added into `PATH`

From the log, it seems that Eclipse is loading its plugins from `.eclipse` in my `/home` directory. How do I get it to load from `/opt`, or its root directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse can't start because it can't find the system library `libXtst.so.6`:

```
/home/alex/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.0_1473617060/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/154/2/.cp/libswt-pi-gtk-4233.so: libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

You can resolve this by installing the missing package:

```
pacman -S libxtst
```

Comment: Wow that works. I should stop skimming my error logs then